# Best format for sending Timestamps to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java, html, rest

When sending timestamps to JavaScript using REST for example I could use different formats.

```
long timeInMillis = (new Date()).getTime();
```

or:

```
String timeInMillis = ""+(new Date()).getTime();
```

**What is the preferred way of sending timestamps to JavaScript is it as long or as String from Java?**

Comment: primarily opinion based?

Comment: Obviously as **String**, since request data are always passed/sent as text

Comment: This question is waaay too broad. It really depends on what you're planning on using the timestamp for, what JS libraries you are using, etc etc. I just can't decide whether to vote to close because it's too broad, it's opinion-based, or because it's unclear what you're asking!

Comment: I plan to use the timestamp as timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using REST and get your data as JSON, the usual case is sending your time as timestamp and convert it to Date in client side (so, for example, you could print it nicely).

for example, the following JSON object:

```
{"currentDate": 1454517934}
```

You can use [Date js object](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp) to initiate new Date with:

```
var newDate = Date(object.currentDate);
```

but if you'll save your timestamp as string you doesn't have matching constructor to initiate `Date(string)`

Hope that's help..

Comment: @confile Did it help you?